# WPF: Displaying templated objects

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

This seems basic, but I want to display a representation of some CLR objects that currently exist in a DataContext.

I've already set up DataTemplates for how I want them to look, I just want to plop them into the visual space.

I tried this, but it doesn't help:

```
            <StackPanel>
                <Binding Path="CalibrationA" />
                <Binding Path="CalibrationB" />
            </StackPanel>
```

The template, for reference (its for a sensor calibration):

```
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ns:CalibrationTable}">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TableName}" />
                        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding KeyName}" />
                            <TextBox Width="50"></TextBox>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ValueName}" />
                            <TextBox Width="50"></TextBox>
                            <Button Content="Add" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class you're looking for is ContentPresenter:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ContentPresenter Content={Binding Foobar1} />
    <ContentPresenter Content={Binding Foobar1} />
<StackPanel>
```